# How to create a Slanted Background with CSS?

Tags: html, css, background

I've attached a picture to show the exact layout. The line in the photo is only there to show where the colors should change.

Here is some code I have tried but doesn't look how I want.

```css
.block {
  background-color: black;
  left: -50;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="block">

  </div>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: What about creating an image and using that as a background?

Comment: That's a bad advice as it uses more resources and the website becomes heavy on load and also it's not responsive. This can be accomplished with CSS with 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use pseudo element with skew transformation :

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: yellow;
}

body:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  background: #000;
  transform: skew(-30deg);
  transform-origin:top;
}
```

To keep the same visual on resize, set a *big* fixed height for the pseudo element and center it:

```css
html {
  background: yellow;
}

html:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(50% - 1000px);
  left: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height:2000px;
  background: #000;
  transform: skew(-15deg);
  transform-origin:top;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Use a linear gradient at an angle

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 }

div {
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(105deg, black 25%, yellow 25%)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: @TemaniAfif Good catch! In Firefox 57 there's hardly any difference. Chrome 63, on the other hand, renders the gradients with pretty rough jagged edges. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48hqy4ye/) for a side-by-side comparison. Probably browsers applying different anti aliasing. Possibly, as you said, because the gradient function isn't intended for such sharp transitions? Just a thought!

Comment: @TemaniAfif The solution seems to be to roughen (as in, opposite of round) the numbers: maybe '24.98%' or better 'calc(25% +1px)'... last seems to have better results in more browsers but not always.

Answer (score 1):

```
.left-sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  background: #000;
  transform: skewY(5px);
}
.content {
  background: #fff;
}
```

The property that "curves" the `div` is this property in CSS `transform: skew(X,Y)`.Try that, hope it helps.

But I suggest that you create 2 `div` side-by-side in order to get the desired effect.